# angularjs : sorting using application statuses?

Tags: angularjs, sorting, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to do sorting based on application status.

I have in my application many statuses :

```
notStarted,
inProgress,
declined,
accepted,
manual,
outOfService,
Review

<div ng-repeat="item in Data | orderBy:'Status'>
</div>
```

orderBy status sort this entire data on alphabatical order. I want to sort based on below order :

```
accepted,
inProgress,
outOfService,
Review,
manual,
declined,
notStarted
```

Any Idea how to do it on angularjs?

Comment: Can you provide your controller codes?

Comment: no controller codes yet! I have to write it accordingly.

Comment: If you can sort in a controller than you can sort in a custom sort function, which is where it belongs (if the only purpose of it is to sort for display)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom sort function in `ng-repeat`, like below:

```
$scope.statusSortFn = function(item) {

    var sortMap = {
    'accepted': 1,
    'inProgress': 2,
    'outOfService': 3,
    'Review': 4,
    'manual': 5,
    'declined': 6,
    'notStarted': 7,
    }

   return sortMap[item.Status];
}
```

Then in the HTML,

```
ng-repeat="item in Data | orderBy:statusSortFn"
```

Comment: It's not possible to value statuses It's coming from other domain. only text we can use.

Comment: The keys to that sort map _are_ text, if `item.Status` is not text you just adapt it so that you can use a _function_ to sort through your data, `orderBy` can use functions too not just object fields